# Javascript For of Loop doesn't break

Tags: javascript, arrays, break, for-of-loop

I have one object and one array.

object:

```json
{
  "topic": "add",
  "payload": { "id": 1, "end": "24:00", "temp": 21, "add": 0, "delete": 0 },
  "row": -1,
  "socketid": "SSZY-1C3jiP8-NS2AAAB",
  "_msgid": "a891f409.e30038"
}
```

array:

```json
[{
  "woche": "Montag",
  "status": 0,
  "_children": [{ "id": 1, "end": "24:00", "temp": 21, "add": 0, "delete": 0 }]
}, {
  "woche": "Dienstag",
  "status": 0,
  "vortag": 1,
  "_children": [{ "id": 2, "end": "24:00", "temp": 21, "add": 0, "delete": 0 }]
}, {
  "woche": "Mittwoch",
  "start": "",
  "status": 0,
  "vortag": 1,
  "_children": [{ "id": 3, "end": "24:00", "temp": 21, "add": 0, "delete": 0 }]
}, {
  "woche": "Donnerstag",
  "status": 0,
  "vortag": 1,
  "_children": [{ "id": 4, "end": "24:00", "temp": 21, "add": 0, "delete": 0 }]
}, {
  "woche": "Freitag",
  "start": "",
  "status": 0,
  "vortag": 1,
  "_children": [{ "id": 5, "end": "24:00", "temp": 21, "add": 0, "delete": 0 }]
}, {
  "woche": "Samstag",
  "start": "",
  "status": 0,
  "vortag": 1,
  "_children": [{ "id": 6, "end": "24:00", "temp": 21, "add": 0, "delete": 0 }]
}, {
  "woche": "Sonntag",
  "start": "",
  "status": 0,
  "vortag": 1,
  "_children": [{ "id": 7, "end": "24:00", "temp": 21, "add": 0, "delete": 0 }]
}]
```

Now I compare the Id and if it matches I want to insert a new object. But now it doesn't break after one insert. Can somebody help me?

```
var Id = global.get("WochenplanID");
var index = 0;
global.set("table",[{"woche":"Montag","status":0,"_children":[{"id":1,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Dienstag","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":2,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Mittwoch","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":3,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Donnerstag","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":4,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Freitag","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":5,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Samstag","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":6,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]},{"woche":"Sonntag","start":"","status":0,"vortag":1,"_children":[{"id":7,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0}]}]
);

var msg = {"topic":"add","payload":{"id":1,"end":"24:00","temp":21,"add":0,"delete":0},"row":-1,"socketid":"SSZY-1C3jiP8-NS2AAAB","_msgid":"a891f409.e30038"};


if (msg.topic == "add") {
    for (var element of global.get("table")) {
        element._children.filter((child) => {
            if (child.id === msg.payload.id) {
                index = element._children.indexOf(child);
                element._children.splice(index, 0, {
                    "id": Id,
                    "end": "",
                    "temp": 21,
                    "add": 0,
                    "delete": 0
                });
            }
        })
    break;
    }
}

msg.payload = global.get("table");
return msg;
```

Comment: Your use of `.filter()` doesn't make much sense, as you're (A) not using the returned array and (B) splicing new elements into the existing array inside the callback. Also your `break` statement will terminate the `for ... of` once the `.filter()` call returns (if it ever does) whether or not a new entry was added.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now :D
I don't know why I didn't saw It thx

Comment: I'm sure you could reduce this example down to a runnable snippet to make it more concise.  Really isolate the problem down to a very small amount of code.  e.g.: replace `global.get` with just a constant (the result of the `get`)